# Flashing twrp failed on Moto G5s

Tags: twrp, fastboot, bootloader, flashtool

I wanted to install twrp on Moto G5s but faced the following error:

```
Inspiron-7501:~/Downloads$ fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.5.img
(bootloader) is-logical:recovery: not found
Sending 'recovery' (15714 KB)                      OKAY [  0.711s]
Writing 'recovery'                                 (bootloader) Image not signed or corrupt
OKAY [  0.132s]
Finished. Total time: 0.848s
```

I tried multiple recovery images, including lineage recovery, and, as i mentioned, twrp.
I checked for the right files for my device (montana) and unlocked the bootloader previously.

If someone has an idea, i would appreciate some help.
Thanks in advance, Bennett.

Comment: Is your device bootloader unlocked?

Comment: yes it is, also according to settings.

Comment: In Android settings you only see "OEM unlock" which allows/disallows unlocking, but the question is if you have really have unlocked your device (e.g. via fastboot).